# Set multiple fields with one update query

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

The following code should work. I could have missed something, but right now I have it as 2 separate update statements and have decided to ask here why this line isn't working.

```
$this->db->settings->update(array('_id' => $mongoID),
  array(
    '$set' => array('about' => $about),
    '$set' => array('avatar' => $avatar)
  )
);
```

Did I miss something when reading guides or is it only possible to do with separate update statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to [**`MongoCollection::update`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php#refsect1-mongocollection.update-parameters) is an array of options for the update operation.

```
$this->db->settings->update(
    array('_id' => $mongoID),
    array('$set' => array('about' => $about, 'avatar' => $avatar))
);
```